# Hook requires data from another hook, but getting Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm getting Error:

> Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

I found some answers saying I should put all hook calls on the top.

However, in the following code, `session` prints `undefined` 3 times while it's loading until it prints the `session` object the fourth time.

Hence, I added a check for the `loading` state.

```js
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/client";
import { request } from "graphql-request";
import useSWR from "swr";

export default function Profile() {
  const [session, loading] = useSession();

  if (loading) {
    return <p className="">loading...</p>;
  }
  if (!session) {
    signIn();
  }

  const { data: user } = useSWR([USER_QUERY, session.email], (query, email) =>
    request("/api/graphql", query, { email })
  );

  return (
    <div className="">
      <p className="">{session.user.nickname}</p>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, this is throwing an error.

A workaround for this particular issue is to define a `NextAuth` callback for `session`, but I don't think that's the correct way to fix it, since I definitely will need to make other hook calls based on the value in the `session` object in the future.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because hooks are tracked by array index internally by React, you can't invoke them conditionally. You need the [same hook calls in the same order](https://hy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) each time a given component renders.

You could move the `useSWR` and subsequent markup to a separate component to avoid the conditional hook calls.

In the example below I've moved the signIn call to a separate component too, but that's not strictly necessary. If you wanted to leave that inline you could just return null instead.

```
export default function Profile() {
  const [session, loading] = useSession();

  if (loading) {
    return <p className="">loading...</p>;
  }

  return !session ? <SignIn /> : <UserStuff />
}

function SignIn () {
  signIn();
  return null;
}

function UserStuff () {
  const { data: user } = useSWR([USER_QUERY, session.email], (query, email) =>
    request("/api/graphql", query, { email })
  );

  return (
    <div className="">
      <p className="">{session.user.nickname}</p>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
    </div>
  );

}
```